# Problem while ordering an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Well I have a PHP array like this:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => post9.post 
    [3] => post8.post 
    [4] => post4.post 
    [5] => post7.post 
    [6] => post5.post 
    [7] => post10.post 
    [8] => post3.post 
    [9] => post6.post 
    [10] => post1.post 
    [11] => post2.post 
)
```

But after trying all the PHP array functions I don't manage to sort it in this way:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => post10.post 
    [1] => post9.post 
    [2] => post8.post 
    [3] => post7.post 
    [4] => post6.post 
    [5] => post5.post 
    [6] => post4.post 
    [7] => post3.post 
    [8] => post2.post 
    [9] => post1.post 
)
```

I already made a question like this, which seemed to work but now it doesn't works :(

**EDIT:** After using `rsort`it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => post9.post
    [1] => post8.post
    [2] => post7.post
    [3] => post6.post
    [4] => post5.post
    [5] => post4.post
    [6] => post3.post
    [7] => post2.post
    [8] => post10.post
    [9] => post1.post
)
```

Almost good, except that post10.post should be `[0]` and is `[8]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) and then reverse the order.

```
 natsort($array);
 $array = array_reverse($array);
```

Comment: I'll mark as correct when StackOverflow allows me :) (I mean this: http://p.fr.am/soI9)